# is it possible to encrypt columns of a table in mysql DB

Tags: mysql, encryption

Is there any way (native MySQL functions or SQL syntax) to encrypt the columns of a table in MySQL database?

Comment: You mean to values of the records for specific columns?

Comment: Yes I mean only for the values for a specific column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL has a wide range of built-in encryption functions, you can find a detailled overview here: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

You might want to have a look at e.g. AES_DECRYPT() and AES_ENCRYPT().

```
INSERT INTO table (mycolumn) VALUES(AES_ENCRYPT('Hello!', 'encryption_key'));
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(mycolumn, 'encryption_key') FROM table;
```

Answer (score 1):

For encryption functions you can look at: [encryption-functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html)